# How do I publish my MySQL code to Github?

Tags: github, mysql-workbench

I don't know how to publish or push my code written in MySQL Workbench to a Github repository so I can showcase it to potential employers.  I want to be able to make a resume with different projects in my Github repositories then add the links to the various projects on my resume by adding the link from a particular repository.  But I don't know how to connect MYSQL Workbench to my Github account.

I don't know where to look.  I tried Google, Youtube videos, now I am asking on here for help.  Do I HAVE TO use Visual Studio when using Workbench?  I haven't used Visual Studio before, but remember it mentioned in a YT video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Workbench specifically, but I think it's better to start from basics of the git.
You can save your SQL queries in separate files and then create a repository in github, connect to it and push your changes.
You can read more about how to start with git [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository):
Than I believe there is a solution to run your SQL files in the Workbench without manually copying it to the console everytime.

If you are using VSCode you can also connect your github account using VSCode. Look for Source Control